# Changing the categories in a column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iterator, iteration

I was experimenting with iter function on pandas.

1- I made a list from a pandas column.

> in1:

```
df_area_code_iter = iter(df["Area Code"])
df_area_code_iter_list = list(df_area_code_iter)
df_area_code_iter_list
```

> out_1:

```
['Area 1',
 'Area 2',
 'Area 1',
 ...
 'Area 0']
```

2- Then I wanted to iterate through the elements of the list to replace Area 0 with PASS THIS.

> in_2:

```
new_column = []

for i in df_area_code_iter_list:
    if i == "Area 0":
       i == "PASS THIS"
    new_column.append(i)

new_column
```

> out_2:

```
['Area 1',
 'Area 2',
 'Area 1',
 ...
 'Area 0']
```

I know there are other methods to replace the values in a column. However, I want to figure it out by converting the dataframe to a list and then iterating over the elements.

> in_3:

```
df["Area Code"] = df["Area Code"].replace(to_replace ="Area 0", value = 
"PASS THIS")
df["Area Code"]
```

> out_3:

```
0          Area 1
1          Area 2
2          Area 1
3          Area 1
4       PASS THIS
5       PASS THIS
6       PASS THIS
...     ....
```

As I said, I am experimenting and I cannot see any reason as to why the for loop at in_2 is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is assignment requires `=`, not the equality operator `==`.

You are forced to append to a new list since the variable `i` inside your loop is a scalar, not a reference pointing to an element in your original list. Instead, you can use `enumerate` and modify your existing list:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(df_area_code_iter_list):
    if val == "Area 0":
        df_area_code_iter_list[idx] = "PASS THIS"
```

Or, more Pythonic, use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [x if x != 'Area 0' else 'PASS THIS' for x in df_area_code_iter_list]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, just changing the double equal to single equal fixed the problem.

Comment: @mcagriardic, Sure, I've updated to show you a way to just modify your existing list.